# Symfony CLI server use of mkcert certificates

Tags: symfony, server, ssl-certificate, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mkcert

I am currently using Symfony with react and webpack to build an application. I use the Symfony CLI development server. I would like to turn this application into a Progressive Web Application (PWA) according to the cookbook at [PWA Workshop](https://pwa-workshop.js.org/). However, according to the information I'm gathering, a fully trusted SSL certificate is required for mobile testing, etc. and the use of [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) is recommended (or maybe Let'sEncrypt). I've already followed the process to [enable TLS on the Symfony CLI server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#enabling-tls). However, the certificates generated appear to be self-signed and are not a fully trusted. Is there a way either call the trusted mkcert certificates from the Symfony CLI server command line or reference them in Symfony config files so that the server uses them instead of the self-signed ones generated by the `symfony server:ca:install` command? (mkcert appears to generate two .pem files and other non-php development servers such as [http-party/http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server#readme) can call them direct from the command line.) My work around is to configure my local apach2 server with the certificates, but I'd like to keep using the Symfony server for debugging.

**UPDATE**
I failed to mention that my development environment is WSL2 on windows 10. That seems to be the problem with getting trusted certificates to work. Since the browsers run in Windows and the servers run in WSL, the windows browsers don't accept the certificates. My current work around for mkcert and apache2 running on WSL is to:

1. Install mkcert on both WSL and Windows, Running `mkcert -install` in both WSL and Windows,
2. Copy the windows root certs from the Trusted Store created in Windows to the Trusted store created in WSL. You find these stores in both environments by running `mkcert -CAROOT` in the respective environments,
3. Run `mkcert localhost 127.0.0.1` and add cert pair to a folder somewhere according to mkcert's instructions,
4. Then configure apache2 to use SSL and the mkcert cert pair according to instructions found all over the internet.

I found this workaround at [mkcert solution](https://www.haveiplayedbowie.today/blog/posts/secure-localhost-with-mkcert/).

However, this issue still remains for the Symfony Server. It is unclear where the certificates (root or otherwise) are installed when `symfony server:ca:install` is run and whether there is a way to make copies of those certificates such that the servers can be run in WSL and windows will accept them. Also, the Symfony docs don't indicate whether those certs are just self-signed or if they are trusted root certs like mkcert.